# Python subprocess running in background before returning output

Tags: python, linux, linux-kernel, subprocess, perf

I have some Python code that I want to debug with perf. For that purpose I want to use subprocess. The following command returns instruction-related information of a process until the command is exited via Ctrl^C.

```
perf stat -p <my_pid>
```

Now, I want to run this inside a Python code in background, until some point where I want to be able to terminate its operation and print the commands output. To show what I mean:

```
x = subprocess.call(["perf","stat","-p",str(GetMyProcessID())])

.. CODE TO DEBUG ..

print x   # I want to terminate subprocess here and output 'x'
```

Now, I want to determine what to do at the line of 'print x' to terminate the process and check the output.
Any idea/help is appreciated.

Cheers and thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: I advise against calling `perf` from within your python process (as you see in the complexity of the task below), but instead use is from the command line:

```
sudo perf stat -- python test.py
```

If you **really** want to call perf from within python then you'll face some tricky problems:

1. to terminate `perf` and make it output the gathered performance stats you need to send it the `SIGINT` signal (try it out with `sudo perf stat -p mypid`: `ctrl-\` will print nothing whereas `ctrl-c` will)
2. you need to capture `stderr` as perf sends its output to `stderr` (at least in my version)
3. you need to use `fork()` with one process sending `SIGINT` and the other reading it's output while the process dies. Without forks it won't work because after you `SIGINT`ed the `perf` process you cannot read from stdin any more as the process is already gone, and when you read from `stdin` first you won't get any output until perf is correctly terminated.

That means you'd end up with this python program:

```
import subprocess
import os
import signal
import time

perf = subprocess.Popen(['perf', 'stat',  '-p', str(os.getpid())], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# <-- your code goes here

if os.fork() == 0:
    # child
    time.sleep(1)  # wait until parent runs `stderr.read()`
    perf.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
    exit(0)

# parent
print("got perf stats>>{}<<".format(perf.stderr.read().decode("utf-8")))
```

The `time.sleep(1)` bit is ugly, what it does it that it will but I guess it will do the trick for 99% of the cases. It has almost no influence on the perf data, the only influence it has is on the "total runtime" (`*xx seconds time elapsed`)

Comment: This seems like its really close to what I would want. One question though: Since perf takes stats dynamically, any delay in the system such as time.sleep increases the number of instructions (therefore,error) in the output. Is there any way to do this without sleep?

Comment: Another thing is that I have perf output but with a Fatal IO error 11. Should I expect this error ?

Comment: Still, gives me an idea of instructions, Thank you.

Comment: @mozcelikors yes, you could do so with threads, I'll have a look later because I'm curious. Btw: doing a sleep has hardly any influence on the perf data, the only influence it has is on the "total runtime" *`xx seconds time elapsed`)

Comment: @mozcelikors with threads it would get a lot more complex, plus you still had the problem of synchronizing the two threads. I would go with the sleep solution, as it does not pollute your stats (you could try with `sleep(0.1)`)

Comment: but overall: I would not choose this solution, you'd rather should run perf directly from the command line, I added this option at the top of my answer

Answer (score 5):

Use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) to run `perf`. Then, use [`pipe.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to send input and get the process's output.

After you've done, call [`pipe.terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) to terminate the process.

For example:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perf","stat","-p",str(GetMyProcessID())], stdout=PIPE)

pipe.terminate()
stdout, stderr = pipe.communicate()
print stdout
```

Comment: Hello, I want to send pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perf","stat","-p",str(GetMyProcessID())]) and output before terminated. I dont have to send any input command but Popen. Now the program gets stuck at 
stdout, stderr = pipe.communicate(None) line. What am I supposed to do? Thanks

Comment: @mozcelikors I should have used `stdout=PIPE` as a parameter to subproces.Popen. I update the answer.

Comment: but still the pipe.communicate is blocking. I need something nonblocking. Or simply I want to get the output when pipe is terminated. So it should run when I call it, but the output should return as I terminate it.

Comment: @mozcelikors Try maybe to terminate it before calling `communicate`.

Comment: I just tried it, then the output is not there since the pipe had been terminated. I just read that Popen.communicate does not return until the process has terminated.