# Read from a subprocess PIPE after process is terminated

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, pipe

I have some Python code that I want to debug with perf. 
Now, the thing with perf is that it gives the output when the process is terminated, I want to do the same via a Python script.

```
perf stat -p <my_pid>
```

I want to run this inside a Python code in background, until some point where I want to be able to terminate its operation and print the commands output. To show what I mean:

```
x = subprocess.Popen(["perf","stat","-p",str(GetMyProcessID())], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

.. CODE TO DEBUG ..

#Terminate the process and get the output after ??
```

Is something like this possible ?

**EDIT:** This is not a duplicate question, I have tried to refine my question and its title as I have more clear understanding about it right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python subprocess running in background before returning output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654499/python-subprocess-running-in-background-before-returning-output)

Comment: You could link stdout to a log file, and the print the contents out later.

Comment: Do you have any link to guide me how to do it?